# Removing NULL values from INNER JOIN with something like WHERE value IS NOT NULL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I would like to ignore NULL values for an INNER JOIN MySQL code embedded in a PHP file.

Below is the line of code that works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee_index 
INNER JOIN seating_index 
  ON employee_index.employee_email = seating_index.seating_identifier
```

Below is something like what I want to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee_index 
INNER JOIN seating_index 
  ON employee_index.employee_email = seating_index.seating_identifier 
WHERE seating_identifier IS NOT NULL
```

I have this code that generates buttons on an office floor plan and labels them with the proper employee name.  Everything about this code works except that empty seats in the office are filled with junk data from the employee list that still includes some non employee vales that contain NULL.  I can fix the issue by cleaning up the employee database, but would like to have code ignore those NULL values automatically.  Below is the full PHP & MySQL code:

```
<?php
//for adding employees based on the seating chart.
include("functions.php");

$counter_loop = 0;
$conn = database_connect();

$category_query = "SELECT * FROM employee_index INNER JOIN seating_index ON 
employee_index.employee_email = seating_index.seating_identifier";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $category_query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?> <?php $counter_loop = 0; ?>

<a href="<?php echo "employee_details.php?ID={$row['employee_email']}" ?>"> 
    <button id="<?php echo $row['seating_space']?>" class="Office_Room" style="
    top: <?php echo $row['seating_top']?>%; 
    left: <?php echo $row['seating_left']?>%;">

    <?php echo $row['employee_first_name'];?>
    <?php echo $row['employee_middle_name'];?>
    <?php echo $row['employee_last_name'];?>

    <?php $counter_loop = $counter_loop + 1; ?>
    </button></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Below is a basic layout of the database these values come from:

Office_database                  <--(database)

- employee_index                 <--(table)

  - employee_email
  - employee_first_name
  - employee_last_name
- seating_index                  <--(table)

  - seating_identifier
  - seating_top
  - seating_left

Below is an example of the values on the employee_index.
Office locations don't have emails, thus are null.
employee_email  /   employee_first_name   /  employee_last_name

- johnd@company.com / John           /         Doe
- janed@company.com / Jane           /         Doe
- NULL / Reception           /         Desk
- bobs@company.com /  Bob            /         Smith

Below is an example of the values on the seating_index.
Empty offices don't have emails, thus are null.
seating_identifier  /   seating_top   /  Seating_left

- johnd@company.com / 20           /         20
- NULL / 60           /         20
- janed@company.com / 40           /         20
- bobs@company.com /  40           /         60

The above results in John Doe, Jane Doe, and Bob Smith being properly displayed in their offices, but the empty office shows Reception Desk.

I plan on removing non employees from the employee list which did work in the test I ran, but I would like to ensure that nulls don't link data between the two databases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `WHERE seating_identifier IS NOT NULL` -- This is not needed, since the inner join never matches nulls.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It seems the problem may be  occurring somewhere else in the data.

Comment: Might be a silly question but is the seating identifier an employes email address?

Comment: Yes, I know I should be using ID, but because people that don't know how to code are going to need to do basic upkeep on this, I needed a unique identifier that won't change.  We have some employees with the same names, plus they switch offices, ect.  The email is unique to each employee, which allows me to tell anyone, just label the txt or jpg employee@company, keeps it simple for those that don't code.